# How to add multiple dynamic styles to a React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component that already has a style attached to it:

```
    <Link onClick={handleCollapse}>
      <KeyboardArrowDownIcon className=(classes.icon) />
      Advanced Options
    </Link>
```

I want to add an additional class to that component when it is clicked. So I tried:

```
   const [collapse, setCollapse] = React.useState(false);

   const handleCollapse = () => {
     setCollapse(prevState => !prevState);
   };

    <Link onClick={handleCollapse}>
      <KeyboardArrowDownIcon
        className={clsx(
          classes.icon,
          collapse ? 'classes.iconActive' : null
        )}
      />
      Advanced Options
    </Link>
```

Since I am already using `collapse` which is a boolean I thought I could just use it to check if it's true or false.

However, the above doesn't work.

Would anyone know what I could do to get this to work?

Comment: Should you write `collapse ? classes.iconActive : null` instead of `collapse ? 'classes.iconActive' : null`? (remove the quotes around classes.iconActive) You can even do `collapse && classes.iconActive`.

Comment: @Hangindev ah, right! Many thanks!

Comment: @MeltingDog I updated my answer to use clsx in the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistakenly quote the variable `classes.iconActive`, write `collapse ? classes.iconActive : null` or `collapse && classes.iconActive` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatinate to the className conditionally.

```
const [collapse, setCollapse] = React.useState(false);

const handleCollapse = () => {
 setCollapse(prevState => !prevState);
};

<Link onClick={handleCollapse}>
  <KeyboardArrowDownIcon
    className={clsx({
    [classes.icon] : true, //always apply
    [classes.iconActive] : collapse //only when collapse === true
   })}
  />
  Advanced Options
</Link>
```